# Paste Copied File From Clipboard To File System

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

If the user has copied a file to the clipboard in the file system, I would like the user to return to an Excel spreadsheet and click a button. The code behind this button should paste this file to a predefined folder.

I know it is possible through VBA to read/write a string to/from the clipboard. Is it possible in VBA to read a copied file from the clipboard and place it in a folder (file doesn't need to be opened during this operation)?

Comment: I think that getting the shell to properly *paste* would be difficult, here is how to fetch the names of the files so that you can `FileCopy()` them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2913670/246342

Comment: Don't tag VBA questions as VB6.

Comment: Bob, according to the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-and-vba , VBA and VB6 is basically the same language, hence my inclusion of the VB6 tag. I would assume that the solution to my question could be applied to both VBA and VB6. Note my question about the clipboard is not specific to the Excel object model.

Comment: In VB6 IIRC you can do this directly via the ClipBoard object, which is not available in VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you copy a file to the clipboard in Explorer, the file itself isn't placed on the clipboard (image what would happen if you copy a file of 200GB :) ).  Instead Explorer puts e.g. the file's path on the clipboard in a special clipboard format (i.e. non-textual).  You can read more on the formats at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I haven't worked closely with these clipboard formats, but it seems that in most cases you would look for the CF_HDROP format.  You'd need quite some VBA to massage the data into the file's path, but from there on it's a simple file copy to complete the operation.